# Compiling .NET Core application in VS Community (Different runtimes)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I've been working on a program in .NET Core using VS Code, however I'm really getting over VS Code and want to move back to visual studio, however one thing that is stopping me is I have no idea how to compile for different runtimes, in VS Code I would just type in the terminal something like this:

`dotnet build -c Debug -r linux-x64`

but I have no idea how to do this using VS Community. If someone could help me out that would be great.

Comment: Is this what you want? [https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-set-debug-and-release-configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-set-debug-and-release-configurations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your project and select `Publish` or alternatively select the `Build` tab and select `Publish <ProjectName>`.

From there you can select the `Target Location`, `Configuration`, `Target Framework` and the `Target Runtime`.

[image]